# Correct syntax for "update" in node-red

Tags: node-red

[image: this is the screen with all the output]can someone tell me what is the correct syntax to do an update in Node-red , im using mysql node for database.

this is the one I used but it's wrong :

```
msg.topic = "UPDATE cambio SET cambio_1 = ("msg.payload.cambio_1")";

return msg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL syntax normally doesn't use brackets round the value. So your function node should probably look something like this:

```
msg.topic = "UPDATE cambio SET cambio_1 = " + msg.payload;

return msg;
```

This does assumes that `msg.payload` is a number. If it is a string then you would need to include quotes around the value:

```
msg.topic = "UPDATE cambio SET cambio_1 = '" + msg.payload + "'";

return msg;
```

Comment: now appear this error : Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'field list'

Comment: Feed the output of the function node into a debug node set to show the whole message object and edit the question with the output

Comment: done, the tag is a integer , i used the first update

Comment: Your input `msg.payload` contains just a number, not an object with a `cambio_1` field. I have edited the answer to match the input